# Как спарсить определенный текст?

Tags: php

Получаю информацию с сайта:

```
    include_once('components/simple_html_dom.php');


echo file_get_html('https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?spp=18&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&nm=110383570')->plaintext;
```

Выводится вся информация, нужно получить только значение qty, как это сделать?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: регулярным выражением можно. `preg_match("/\"qty\":(\d+)/",$source,$mth);echo "qty=".$mth[1];` не тестил.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

потестил. Предполагаю, что параметр qty - это цифры.

```
preg_match("/\"qty\":(\d+)/",file_get_contents('https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?spp=18&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&nm=110383570'),$mth);
echo "qty=".$mth[1];
```

Дополнение к задаче:

```
$file=file_get_contents('https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?spp=18&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&nm=26772898;27152838;110383570');
preg_match_all("/basicPriceU\":(\d+)/",$file,$matchPrice);
preg_match_all("/120762,\"qty\":(\d+)/",$file,$matchQty);
$S=0;
foreach($matchPrice[1] as $key => $price){
    $S+=$price*$matchQty[1][$key];
}
echo $S;
```

у меня выполняется за 0.3-0.6мс после рестарта пхп. Быстро.

Comment: Спасибо, работает! Столкнулся с одним нюансом. Бывает такое, что qty дублируется, например: "stocks":[{"wh":117501,"qty":1},{"wh":120762,"qty":601}]. Как брать qty только с наибольшим значением или с "wh":120762", тк wh неизменно?

Comment: ужас.....парсить json регуляркой...это что, новая мода?

Comment: @АлександрКоновалов надо не доверять сомнительным неумным решениям, а работать с массивом, как я писал в ответе.

Comment: ну можно регулярку подправить, да, если wh не изменен. Типа так `/\"wh\":120762,\"qty\":(\d+)/`

Comment: @Андрюха спасибо!

Comment: либо использовать функцию preg_match_all, вытаскивать все qty из документа и находить максимум. Но если wh:120762  неизменно и то, что вам нужно, то проще регулярку подправить, как выше написал.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, иногда json отдаваемый сервером имеет меняющую структуру и спарсить регуляркой будет простым и оптимальным решением. Судя по всему у автора вопроса возникли трудности с разбором структуры массива, так что я предложил иной путь. А у него, как мне кажется структура json меняется как раз, может не прав, предполагаю.

Comment: @Андрюха что значит менять структуру? Во-первых на адекватных сайтах структура определена заранее. Во-вторых, даже если меняется - проще и быстрее работать с массивами . А регулярка, просто к сведению, сжирает ЦП и в некоторых случаях может привести к зависонам. Это довольно дорогая операция. Так что в любом случае ответ плохой!

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  Ну вы прочитали первый коммент автора? место в массиве неоднозначно, возможно несколько qty в массиве. К чему это шаманство по определению  нужного qty в массиве? в моем случае достаточно просто немного подправить регулярку. Далее, вопрос автора: "как спарсить определенный текст?" и регулярные выражения видится оптимальным решением для данного вопроса. Я привел готовое решение, вместо наставнических размышлений о возможных путях решения проблемы. Вопрос-ответ! про зависания регулярок я промолчу, фантазии. Я с вами не согласен, в общем. Дело вкуса и опыта, как решать задачу.

Comment: Место в массиве однозначное. Там оно находится в массиве с ключом stocks. Берём массив, берём ключ stocks, находим минимальное число среди qty. Изи. Так что........."про зависания регулярок я промолчу, фантазии" --- ну удачи вам с этим. Когда ЦП будет у вас сотку жрать при парсинге строки в 1000 символов - вспомните этот разговор

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9hSu.png и https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fjdH.png  - так, на подумать

Comment: вряд ли вспомню, написал парсеры на более чем 100 сайтов..полет нормальный...неумеючи можно и *** сломать. В прочем, по теме я все сказал.

Comment: а кого собственно волнует, что использование регулярных выражений может теоретически(!) грузить цп в данном конкретном случае? тут регэксп простой, как для понимания, так и для вычисления. И что собственно важнее помочь человеку или показать правильный путь, которому конкретно автору вопроса сложно следовать? Мое имхо, что помощь важнее, вопрос решен, значит такое решение имеет право на жизнь.

Comment: "что значит менять структуру?" - путь до подмасива stocks в массиве разобранного json может меняться, необходимо будет дополнительно вытаскивать этот подмассив. Лишняя возня. "изи" - вы не для себя пишите ответ. Мое решение простое, написанное за 30секунд, проигрывает вашему только в вопросе скорости исполнения, а так ли важна скорость? автор же не уточняет. Так что я бы поостерегся называть простые решения - "неумными" :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский поясню подробнее, в данном примере массив Stocks находится по такому пути `$data['data']['products'][0]['sizes'][0]['stocks']` в структуре исходного массива. Но где гарантия, что в приходящем json "путь" до искомого массива не будет `$data['data']['products'][1]['sizes'][1]['stocks']`? а если будут? тогда задача получения нужного qty усложняется имхо.

Comment: @Андрюха здравствуйте! Пользуюсь вашим решением, все отлично работает! Еще раз спасибо! Появилась необходимость брать basicPriceU и умножать на qty, а затем суммировать, полученное произведение, с другими артикулами, которые также перемножаются. К ссылке добавляется несколько артикулов (nm=26772898;27152838;110383570). Возможно это сделать?

Comment: @АлександрКоновалов я опубликовал дополнение к ответу. Посмотрите устроит вас это. Переменная `S` - сумма произведений `(basicPriceU*qty)` соответствующие.

Comment: я, на самом деле реализовал решение по поиску qty и разбором массива. Выигрыш в скорости в 3 раза где-то. Но так как в медленном случае ищется менее миллисекунды то посчитал непринципиальным это. В каком-нибудь грабере в котором еще стоят слипы между запросами то вообще непринципиально. А разбирать массив мне кажется сложнее и дольше. Посему такое решение. :)

Comment: @Андрюха благодарю!

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему это json. Поэтому всё, что нужно, это привести к массиву через `json_decode(СТРОКА, true)` и работать с массивом.

И тогда вместо `file_get_html`  испльзовать `file_get_contents`

Comment: `json_decode(file_get_contents('https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?spp=18&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&nm=110383570')->plaintext, true);`

вот так?

Comment: У `file_get_contents` нет свойства `plaintext`, Оно тут лишнее. Но в целом да.

Comment: `$json = trim(file_get_contents('https://card.wb.ru/cards/detail?spp=18&regions=68,64,83,4,38,80,33,70,82,86,75,30,69,22,66,31,48,1,40,71&pricemarginCoeff=1.0&reg=1&appType=1&emp=0&locale=ru&lang=ru&curr=rub&couponsGeo=12,3,18,15,21&dest=-1029256,-102269,-1278703,-1255563&nm=110383570'));
$data = json_decode($json,true);
echo $data[0]['qty'];`

пробую так, не работает

Comment: Правильно.. Во-первых не `qte`, а `qty`, а во-вторых надо не бездумно тыкать, а сделать например `print_r` и посмотреть внимательно где именно находится ключ